# Does upgrading jQuery UI 1.7.2 to 1.8.7 result in a performance improvement?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, upgrade

My site is only using dialogs and buttons from jQuery UI. In general things are working fine, but from time to time some users are facing light performance issues; the system is not as responsive as it should be in their opinion.

Upgrading from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.4.4 really did a good job, because there are lots of `find()`/`filter()` calls in my code. Should I expect some performance benefits from upgrading jQuery UI?

Comment: Have you run any tests on your own?

Comment: Are you using setInterval anywhere in your code? If so, try to refactor that. Perhaps try to make use of DOMNodeInserted or jQuery.live method.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple things to think about with respect to upgrading a library.

1. How difficult is it going to be to do so. Many times, if it is a minor release upgrade, you're not going to see any API changes or anything of that nature. It should be a fairly smooth process to perform the upgrade. In this case, I don't see any reason why you **wouldn't** perform the upgrade.
2. In the case of going to a more major release, you need to consider the API changes that could cause the upgrade to a new version of a library to take longer. It may not be just a simple idea of "drop in the new library and you're good to go." With that said, I typically try to keep my libraries as up-to-date as possible. Yeah, it may be slightly more work now, but, in the long run, it is easier to upgrade a library on a continual basis than do it once every 5 years.

As for the type of performance improvements you'll see if you upgrade to 1.8.7, check out the [release notes](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/12/jquery-ui-1-8-7/). Not only t should you see improvements, you should also have more feature availability as well.

**With all this said...**

Many times, performance improvements are better affected if the code using the libraries is improved. Better algorithms, better use of structures, etc can show MUCH better improvements than just upgrading a library. I would look into this along with looking at upgrading the jQueryUI library.

Comment: So general idea is "why not it should be at least as good as it was". Is it right?

Comment: @d0rc - Pretty much. As long as there is no expensive upgrade cost to changes in the APIs, I would go for it.

Comment: @d0rc - exactly, as long as it's a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

The release notes say it's lighter - I'd hazard a guess that helped it be a bit quicker too.

Comment: Lighter could mean so much different things. It could cycle rolling to make code smaller for example. Official release note states framework became more modular, one can even choose modules to include in custom compilation. But it also could result in some additional checks when accessing internal objects, checking if classes are available and so on. So for me it is not clear if jqueryui runs faster now.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate your code first.

Use IDs instead of classes wherever possible.

Keep selection operations to a minimum by caching.
Especially true if you are doing this inside a block that gets called often.

For example:

```
if( $('#some-id').find('.foo').length > 0 ) {
  //do something with foos
  console.log($('#some-id').find('.foo'));
}
```

should be

```
var $foos = $('#some-id .foo');
if( $foos.length > 0 ) {
  //do something with foos
  console.log($foos);
}
```

AFTER you have investigated your code and tested.

I would go ahead and upgrade then retest on your local machine first in all browsers.
If everything is fine, why not upgrade?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm aware of such optimization tricks and I was writting code to keep it as fast as possible, testing various parts for performance issues in different browsers. I've even wrote an app, that sends mouse clicks to X screen, and a server-side script counting how many successfull runs system performed during night and so on.